# ASP.Net Website Analytics - What Data to Capture?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am looking to capture a set of data in ASP.Net and send it to a service for processing.  To start with, I will only be interested in a small amount of the data available to the [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class.  For example: IP Address, URL, etc.  My first thought, was to send these specific values to the service for processing.  This will all be stored in a SQL Server database.

However, I began thinking of ways to "future proof" this and started toying with the idea of capturing all [`Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx) and save them as name/value pairs.  I quickly realized that it might also be handy to have access to [`ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) as well.  For example, if [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) was used, I would want to access  `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL` to determine what URL was in the browser.  If I had not thought to capture this value to start with, I would have no way to go back and re-process the data.

As you can see, what started out as a relatively small amount of data is turning out to be a lot more than I had anticipated.  These websites have relatively small amount of traffic, so I probably could save [`ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) for all requests if I had to, but it just seems like overkill.

I know there are services out there like Google Analytics that offer all of this and more, but one important requirement I have is to associate this data with an authenticated user which is strictly against Google's TOS.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to hand-roll your own analytics service?  Is there data outside outside [`ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) that I may need access to?

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Don't rely on Google Analytics as it won't give you the full details of your website. 

Why aren't you using your web server log files (with full auditing enabled) for this project?  This isn't clear in your post.  Also, are there not any 3rd party analytics that can serve your needs?  I've seen very powerful ones that are both free up to fee based.

Comment: I think you might be right that log file parsing is a good approach to take.  This system was originally designed to track user interactions (system logins, file downloads, etc).  I was hoping to extend it to include page views as well, but it looks like that is a whole different beast.  Although it would be nice to have some of the analytics attached to the user activities.  For example, logged in from IP Address X with User Agent Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main question you need to ask yourself is what is the goal of this additional logging?

If it’s to give additional data to sales guys then you’ll most probably need a very small amount of data (which pages were visited and when)

If the purpose is to improve performance then it’s some other set of parameters.

But you need to start with what is the outcome.

I was working on a project where similar system needs to be implemented. Website was based on one main master page and other child pages. I took the Page_Load of the main master page and added all logic in there.

I would have one database table for visitors (tracking id, referring website, created date, authentication ID,  and couple more) one table for each page visit (full page url (with query string, short page url, visit time). There were also two additional tables that help us in scoring how much visit to each page is valuable from marketing perspective.

I’d avoid parsing log files because these contain info on all requests (such as request for image, javascript file, video and more).  Also, log files by default do not contain any login info you can use to associate activities with authenticated users.

Comment: Good point regarding IIS Logs containing info for all resources. This logging is definitely intended for the business folk. One thing I forgot to mention is that there are 50 or so sites that will be calling this service and there is not a real efficient way to update them all at the same time. Even if I ignore a lot of extra data to start, my thought is that it may come in handy at some point time? I do like the idea of identifying exactly what needs to be tracked and only sending that.